# Get the CSRF token in a test, "CSRF token is invalid" - functional ajax test

Tags: ajax, symfony, csrf

I'm trying to test an `ajax` request in Symfony2. I'm writing a unit test which is throwing the following error in my `app/logs/test.log`:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: 
"Impossible to access an attribute ("0") on a string variable 
("The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.")
in .../vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:388
```

My code is fairly straight-forward.

```
public function testAjaxJsonResponse()
{
    $form['post']['title'] = 'test title';
    $form['post']['content'] = 'test content';
    $form['post']['_token'] = $client->getContainer()->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken();

    $client->request('POST', '/path/to/ajax/', $form, array(), array(
        'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
    ));

    $response = $client->getResponse();
    $this->assertSame(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    $this->assertSame('application/json', $response->headers->get('Content-Type'));
}
```

The issue seems to be the `CSRF` token, I could disable it for the tests, but I don't really want to do that, I had it working by making 2 requests (the first one loads the page with the form, we grab the `_token` and make a second request using with `XMLHttpRequest`) - This obviously seems rather silly and inefficient!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Solution

We can generate our own `CSRF` token for our `ajax` request with:

```
$client->getContainer()->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken($intention);
```

Here the variable `$intention` refers to an array key set in your `Form Type Options`.

### Add the `intention`

In your `Form Type` you will need to add the `intention` key. e.g:

```
# AcmeBundle\Form\Type\PostType.php

/**
 *  Additional fields (if you want to edit them), the values shown are the default
 * 
 * 'csrf_protection' => true,
 * 'csrf_field_name' => '_token', // This must match in your test
 *
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Post',
        // a unique key to help generate the secret token
        'intention' => 'post_type',
    ));
}
```

#### [Read the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html#csrf-protection)

### Generate the CSRF Token in your Functional test

Now we have that `intention`, we can use it in our unit test to generate a valid `CSRF` token.

```
/**
 * Test Ajax JSON Response with CSRF Token
 * Example uses a `post` entity
 *
 * The PHP code returns `return new JsonResponse(true, 200);`
 */
public function testAjaxJsonResponse()
{
    // Form fields (make sure they pass validation!)
    $form['post']['title'] = 'test title';
    $form['post']['content'] = 'test content';

    // Create our CSRF token - with $intention = `post_type`
    $csrfToken = $client->getContainer()->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('post_type');
    $form['post']['_token'] = $csrfToken; // Add it to your `csrf_field_name`

    // Simulate the ajax request
    $client->request('POST', '/path/to/ajax/', $form, array(), array(
        'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
    ));

    // Test we get a valid JSON response
    $response = $client->getResponse();
    $this->assertSame(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    $this->assertSame('application/json', $response->headers->get('Content-Type'));

    // Assert the content
    $this->assertEquals('true', $response->getContent());
    $this->assertNotEmpty($client->getResponse()->getContent());
}
```

Comment: Note that as of Symfony 2.3 the service name is `security.csrf.token_manager` instead of `form.csrf_provider`.

Answer (score 2):

While this question is very old, it still pops up as first result on Google, so I'd though I'd update it with my findings using Symfony 5.4 / 6.x.

---

Short answer: use the result of your Form type's `getBlockPrefix()` method as the tokenId:

```php
$csrfToken = self::getContainer()->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken('your_blockprefix');
```

---

Long answer:

This is the place where Symfony creates the CSRF Token within it's form system:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.3/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Csrf/Type/FormTypeCsrfExtension.php#L81

The tokenId will be determined in the following order:

- the form type's option `csrf_token_id` if present
- the form type's block prefix as returned by the `getBlockPrefix()` method if present (see [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html))
- the Entity's class name, converted to lowercase with underscores (see [source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.3/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/StringUtil.php#L44))

Since I didn't want to add the csrf_token_id option to every single Form Type, I wrote the following method to obtain the CSRF Token based on the fully qualified name of a Form Type:

```php
protected function generateCSRFToken(string $formTypeFQN): string
{
    $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($formTypeFQN);
    $constructor = $reflectionClass->getConstructor();
    $args = [];
    foreach ($constructor->getParameters() as $parameter) {
        $args[] = $this->createMock($parameter->getType()->getName());
    }
    /** @var FormTypeInterface $instance */
    $instance = $reflectionClass->newInstance(... $args);
    return self::getContainer()->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken($instance->getBlockPrefix());
}
```

It instantiates an object of the Form Type mocking every required constructor parameter and then creates a CSRF token based on the instance's block prefix.